# Google maps not working in unchecked tabs

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I have a problem with Google Maps.

When I set Google map js in hidden tab it is not working perfectly, it looks like this image:

[image]

but when I set Google map js in a show tab or checked tab, it is working without any problems.

this is my codes

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyA3Z1nKJN0jewM1UzoZwbPUuzf10E3aqHU'></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:492px;width:679px;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:492px;width:679px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='https://www.embedmap.net/'>adding google maps to a website</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=ee55f5ab8a6f63cd2cca9d771703b51f20e75595'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:14,center:new google.maps.LatLng(35.5292113,44.82172779999996),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.5292113,44.82172779999996)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>kurdistan</strong><br>chamchamall<br> <br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

and this is all codes in zip file

http://www.webchinupload.com/f/2016-10/d2d4e6c31c316438d9331a66da93c6ad.zip

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with hidden elements, init the map on show event of that div.

Comment: can you tell me the solution of it with this js function , how do my work with this function?

Comment: this is my all codes in this zip file http://www.webchinupload.com/f/2016-10/d2d4e6c31c316438d9331a66da93c6ad.zip

Comment: I cant see your code on my phone, so just init your map when you are changing tabs visibility